# Dialogflow function deployment issues on Node.js/Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, twilio, dialogflow-es

I am trying to send user SMS texts to Dialogflow in a Firebase function, however I'm receiving the following error when I deploy my functions.  The code for Dialogflow was copied off the DF Node.js library.

```
error  Move function declaration to function body root
```

This is referring to `async function dialogflowMessage()` line.  Maybe I don't fully understand async/await yet, but it seems like my function needs to be nested within the original receive SMS function.  Below is my complete function code for handling incoming texts, checking if SMS, and sending to DF.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true});
const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json'); //firebase service account
const serviceKey = require('./service-key.json');         //Dialogflow service key
const express = require('express');
const async = require('async');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const accountSid = 'REDACTED';  //Twilio acct sid
const authToken = 'REDACTED';     //Twilio auth token
const twilioNumber = '+REDACTED';                      //Twilio phone number
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

exports.processMsg = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  const sid = request.body.MessageSid;
  const body = request.body.Body;

  if (sid.startsWith('SM', 0)) {

    //Start Dialogflow

    async function dialogflowMessage(projectId = 'REDACTED-PROJECT-ID') {
      // A unique identifier for the given session
      const sessionId = uuid.v4();

      // Create a new session
      const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
      const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

      // The text query request.
      const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
          text: {
            // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
            text: body,
            // The language used by the client (en-US)
            languageCode: 'en-US',
          },
        },
      };

      // Send request and log result
      const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
      console.log('Detected intent');
      const result = responses[0].queryResult;
      console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
      console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
      if (result.intent) {
        console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
      }
    }

    //end Dialogflow

  } else if (sid.startsWith('MM', 0)) {
    twiml.message(`This is an image!! ${media}`);
  } else {
    twiml.message(
      'No Body param match, Twilio sends this in the request to your server.'
    );
  }

  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  response.end(twiml.toString());

});
```

Comment: I noticed the function was defined improperly.  I've moved the function to the top level and made the body a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    exports.processMsg = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    
      const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
    
      const sid = request.body.MessageSid;
      const body = request.body.Body;
    
      if (sid.startsWith('SM', 0)) {
    
              dialogflowMessage('REDACTED-PROJECT-ID')
    
      } else if (sid.startsWith('MM', 0)) {
        twiml.message(`This is an image!! ${media}`);
      } else {
        twiml.message(
          'No Body param match, Twilio sends this in the request to your server.'
        );
      }
    

async function dialogflowMessage(projectId = 'REDACTED-PROJECT-ID') {
          // A unique identifier for the given session
          const sessionId = uuid.v4();
    
          // Create a new session
          const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
          const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
    
          // The text query request.
          const request = {
            session: sessionPath,
            queryInput: {
              text: {
                // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
                text: body,
                // The language used by the client (en-US)
                languageCode: 'en-US',
              },
            },
          };
    
          // Send request and log result
          const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
          console.log('Detected intent');
          const result = responses[0].queryResult;
          console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
          console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
          if (result.intent) {
            console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
          } else {
            console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
          }
        }

      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
      response.end(twiml.toString());
    
    });
```